# display caption on image gallery using magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I've been able to get captions to display using Magnific Popup on single images and on galleries with multiple videos, but I can't get captions to display for galleries filled with multiple images.

I want to specify the attribute containing the caption. The title is what is seen when you hover over the element, and I'm trying to use the value of the "description" attribute as the caption, displayed below each image (one caption for all images in the gallery).

Right now, for galleries with multiple images, the only caption it's displaying is the count (1 of 4, etc.).

```js
    $('#myId').magnificPopup({
      items: [{
        src: 'Images/path to image 1',

      }, {
        src: 'Images/path to image 2',

      }, {
        src: 'Images/path to image 3',

      }, {
        src: 'Images/path to image 4',

      }],
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      },
      type: 'image',
      image: {
        titleSrc: 'description'
      }
    });
```

```html
<div class="projectThumb">
  <a id="myId" description="test" href="#" title="myTitle">
    <img src="Images/path to thumb image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try placing the `description` attribute on the `img` element rather than `a` element?

Comment: @damo-s Tried adding the `description` attribute to the `img` element... didn't work.